# Sheet music shown in Picard S3 end credits: what song is this?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-picard

The end credits sequence of Star Trek: Picard season 3 shows sheet music:
[image]

What song do these notes represent?
I've seen people suggest it's "Pop goes the weasel", but I can't confirm because I don't have the required musical reading skills

Comment: Gotta be _Frere Jacques_ eh. Or that one flute tune he learned that time he lived an entire other life in 20 minutes?

Comment: Definitely not "Frere Jacques" since that doesn't have doubled notes like this.  Found a few settings for "Pop goes the weasel," and those match notes 2-10, but this goes in another direction after that.

Comment: [Looper claims](https://www.looper.com/1188115/easter-eggs-in-star-trek-picard-season-3/) (without attribution) that this _is_ "Pop goes the weasel."  Of course it also claims it's in 6/8 time, but the second full bar on the first line has 7 beats...  ([Classic arrangement](https://www.8notes.com/scores/6844.asp) for comparison purposes.)

Comment: It does seem to (almost) be Pop goes the weasel, with a couple of extra notes in the beginning (maybe an extra "With a") before "Half a pound of tuppenny rice".

Comment: Given its significance to Data, "Pop Goes The Weasel" would certainly fit with the credits' other visual references to the characters' past and/or the plot of season 3 itself.

Comment: @DavidW it looks like it was in 6/8 until the graphics guys moved the barlines around. See also the nonsensical beaming and ties.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is indeed *Pop Goes the Weasel*, but written quite irregularly.

I've filled in the end of the first line with what the tune normally is, but the second line is some sort of variation.

In the video below you can hear (and see) the visible tune from the screenshot.

https://i.imgur.com/FZxb1mj.mp4

Comment: Not a musical person myself so I don't know, but I suspect that it is “written irregularly” to better match Data's attempt at the tune in encounter at Farpoint?

Comment: @DavidSpillett not at all. It doesn't change anything about how it sounds. I suspect whoever made the credits just thought it looked better, and had a similar lack of musical knowledge.

Comment: I find that the vast majority of musical notes used as a graphical element turn out to be either gibberish (made by an artist that has no idea how to read music), or just ripped off of something famous but irrelevant (usually Mozart or Beethoven).  It's refreshing to see something that's at least related to the plot in this case.  They hid a lot of stuff in there.  This credit sequence is almost begging for people to pore over it frame by frame looking for stuff like that.